Active Directory and adding attribute via ldif script
I have .ldif file where I can add new attribute for users in my AD and it works fine.
dn: CN=NewUserAttribute,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=local
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: attributeSchema
cn: NewUserAttribute
distinguishedName: 
 CN=NewUserAttribute,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=local
instanceType: 4
attributeID: 1.2.840.113556.1.8000.2024.03.1441
attributeSyntax: 2.5.5.12
isSingleValued: TRUE
uSNChanged: 5167
showInAdvancedViewOnly: TRUE
adminDisplayName: NewUserAttribute
adminDescription: User sync NewUserAttribute
oMSyntax: 64
lDAPDisplayName: NewUserAttribute
name: NewUserAttribute
objectCategory: 
 CN=Attribute-Schema,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=local


dn:
changetype: modify
add: schemaUpdateNow
schemaUpdateNow: 1
-


dn: CN=User,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=local
changetype: modify
add: mayContain
mayContain: NewUserAttribute
-

dn:
changetype: modify
add: schemaUpdateNow
schemaUpdateNow: 1
-

The new attribute got name NewUserAttribute - it's for example
I need to use ldif script to create attribute for groups.
Does anyone have any idea how to modify it to get it done?
